# Patching CloudBuild Triggers

Tags: google-cloud-build

Is there a CLI option for CloudBuild triggers **patch** command?

GCB API version has 'patch' option
https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers/patch

yet gcloud CLI doesn't have 'patch' listed https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/builds/triggers/

I tried `gcloud beta builds triggers patch $trigger_name`, but it didn't work

My use case. I've got a folder with all GCB triggers and I'm using GCB itself to create new/update GCB triggers from trigger.yaml files in that folder. Currently it deletes all the triggers and recreates them from those files. Maybe patching is a better option so that I don't have too many trigger IDs.

```
  steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      echo 'Starting bash'
      for gcb_trigger in folder/triggers/*.yaml; do
        gcloud beta builds triggers delete "$(basename $gcb_trigger .yaml)" --quiet
      done

      for gcb_trigger in folder/triggers/*.yaml; do
        gcloud beta builds triggers create cloud-source-repositories --trigger-config="$gcb_trigger"
      done

      echo 'Finishing bash'
```

Answer (score 1):

Patching triggers is not yet available via `gcloud` command, but it's possible to patch the triggers using the API inside the `curl`.

On curl:

```
curl -X PATCH \
  'https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/triggers/[TRIGGER_NAME]' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
  -H 'Authorization: [ACCESS TOKEN]'\
  -d '{
  "name": "foobar"
}'
```

This request will update the name of your **trigger** to `foobar`.

Take note that before doing this, you need to [supply an access token](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication) for your auth header.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using service acc and keeping access_token somewhere isn't ideal. I tried this route https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/developers, but it didn't work either