# Continue error trying to change Google cloud trigger with REST APIs

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to change a trigger using REST API, specifically https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers/patch. Note that I'm able to use curl and list all the triggers. Also I tried to download the trigger in JSON using https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers/get (which works perfectly) but when I tried to upload the same file the error is always:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "exactly 1 build config required, got: 0",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

if I try to upload an invalid Json correctly it gives error parsing JSON, so surely it's trying to parse using JSON format.

So I tried the same experiment using "Try it!" button on Google page which opens Google APIs explorer. Same results. The interface gave me a warning that some fields are only output so I tried also to remove these fields but I got the same error.

The file I'm trying to upload is (changed some strings to remove company name)

```
{
  "description": "Push to any branch",
  "github": {
    "push": {
      "branch": ".*"
    },
    "owner": "company",
    "name": "repo-utils"
  },
  "tags": [
    "github-default-push-trigger"
  ],
  "name": "default-push-trigger-127"
}
```

Comment: Had a look at https://nieldw.medium.com/put-your-build-triggers-into-source-control-with-the-cloud-build-api-ed0c18d6fcac and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64118275/patching-cloudbuild-triggers, it seems I'm doing the same but it does not help

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the issue. Google API seems to require either `build` or `filename` to be passed to specify a way to build. On the other hand the web interface allows to insert an `Autodetect` option for the build which will try to look for either `cloudbuild.yaml` or `Dockerfile` in the root directory. If you specify `Autodetect` on the web interface the Json configuration won't have either `build` or `filename` so when you try to import back that configuration it will fail.

I tried to pass filename as empty string, the web interface shows a `cloudbuild.yaml` (which is present) but the execution of the trigger fails.

So it seems there's no way to insert a `Autodetect` mode trigger using the API.